# Application Editable Settings (Best Practices)

Tags: php, settings

I am looking for the best way to store the application editable settings (ex: Site Name, Is the site closed? .. etc).

It seems like Database is not the best way because I don't want to use a database just for 2 or 3 settings!

So I went to PHP Array but how can I edit it?!

I have reviewed all questions related to this, but I can not find a useful answer for me.

Note: I don't want to edit the settings manually. I want to edit it by php.

Comment: save it in config file for example `config.ini` or whatever

Comment: Probably better to ask this on Progammers Stack Exchange rather that SO as your question is conceptual rather than a programming issue/bug/problem.

Comment: do you want to edit it with PHP or manually?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/25559382/508666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the settings in a config file in form of serialized array or JSON.

Say, reading settings:

```
$settings = json_decode( file_get_contents('settings.cfg') );
```

Saving settings back:

```
file_put_contents('settings.cfg', json_encode($settings) );
```

Of course the file should be writeable permission wise.

You can store anything you want in this array, even simple objects and complex arrays. And as it is JSON you can edit the file manually, too. If a need arises.

Comment: Sometimes I just edit the site name for example, is it good practice to save all the settings everytime?

Comment: With PHP it doesn't matter. You will rewrite the file anyway. Unless you have megabytes of settings there, it's nothing.