# How to open a file and write in between the Double quotes in php

Tags: php

I have a php file that looks like

```
$tab ="
<th>Waste Collected</th>
<th>2010</th>
<th>2011</th>
<th>2012</th>
<th>2013</th>
<th>2014</th>
<th>2015</th>";
```

Now I want to write **2016** in between the double quote but its writing outside the double quote.

I want it to be like

```
$tab ="
    <th>Waste Collected</th>
    <th>2010</th>
    <th>2011</th>
    <th>2012</th>
    <th>2013</th>
    <th>2014</th>
    <th>2015</th>
<th>2016</th>";
```

here is the code

```
$myfile = fopen("table_call.php", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$tb = '<th>2016</th>';
fwrite($myfile, $tb);

fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558820/how-do-i-use-php-to-edit-a-variable-in-another-php-script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do this to include the file in and you have access to teh variable $tab.  You write back $tab and $tb

```
require_once "table_call.php";

$myfile = fopen("table_call.php", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$tb = '<th>2016</th>';
fwrite($myfile, $tab.$tb);

fclose($myfile);
```